# express and socket.io: pass var io to router

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have spend the last couple of hours figuring out how to combine socket.io with express routers
Im trying to get socket.io work.

This are the packages I use:

```
"express": "~4.9.0",
"ejs": "~0.8.5",
"socket.io":"~1.3.3"
```

my app.js:

```
// loading modules
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//routers
var secretRouter = require('./routes/secret');

// Setup serving static assets
app.use(express.static('public'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// Setup initial routing - index
app.use('/', secretRouter);


// Start the server
server.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('App listening at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

my secret router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Show the login form
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.req = req;
  res.render('secret/login');
});

// If someone tries to login
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
username = req.body.username;
password = req.body.password;
req.getConnection(function(err, connection){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ?',[username, password], function(err, results) {
  res.locals.data = results;
  if (results.length > 0){
    req.session.regenerate(function(){
    req.session.login = true;
    req.session.username = req.body.username;
    res.redirect(req.baseUrl);
    });
  }else {
console.log('wachtwoord of naam is fout');
res.redirect(req.baseUrl);
}
});
}); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

This all works fine.

I can add a io connection function that let me know if someone opened the site like this in the app.js:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

But now instead of having the above code in app.js I want it in the secret router. But just putting it in the secret router will give me an error saying io is not defined.

So somehow I need to pass the io var to the router.

EDIT:

In my app.js I changed:
    var secretRouter = require('./routes/secret');

to:

```
var secretRouter = require('./routes/secret')(io);
```

and in my secret router:

```
module.exports = function(io) { // catch here

var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

return router;
}

// Show the login form
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.req = req;
  res.render('secret/login');
});

// If someone tries to login
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
username = req.body.username;
password = req.body.password;
req.getConnection(function(err, connection){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ?',[username, password], function(err, results) {
  res.locals.data = results;
  if (results.length > 0){
    req.session.regenerate(function(){
    req.session.login = true;
    req.session.username = req.body.username;
    res.redirect(req.baseUrl);
    });
  }else {
console.log('wachtwoord of naam is fout');
res.redirect(req.baseUrl);
}
});
}); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

But now I get the error that router is not defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just pass it

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var secretRouter = require('./routes/secret')(io); // pass here

app.use('/', secretRouter);
```

and then catch it in the secret router

```
module.exports = function(io) { // catch here

    var express = require('express');
    var router  = express.Router();

    // ...routes

    return router;
}
```

Comment: if I do this it will say router is not defined?

Comment: It shouldn't, it returns the same thing you're doing now, `router`, it just wraps it in a function to pass the `io` argument

Comment: I made an edit to my post with the new code that gives me the router is not defined error

Comment: Remove the last line, `module.exports = router;` which is overwriting the first export.

Comment: that solved it. Could you include the fiddle in your answare as final solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: You saved my day!